# Distance between elements in the list

Tags: python, list, distance

I am trying to get a distance (in indexes) between elements in the simple list.  Here is what I have figured out:

```
def cos():
    x = "simpletext"
    testing = []
    my_x = [y for y in x]
    for let in my_x:
        if my_x.index(let) > 2 and my_x.index(let) < 7:
        testing.append(my_x.index(let))
        return testing

print(cos())
```

The output is [3], but it should be [3,4,5,6] - these indexes are between 2 and 7.  While having all indexes between elements x[2] to x[7] I would be able to get the distance.

Comment: Please give a specific example of what you mean by "distance".  If you already know the limits (2 and 7), you simply subtract them to get the distance.  There's no need for the string.

Comment: Ok I messed up.Imagine this:I have a string, which is a series of letters and I want to know the distance between these letters in the alphabet.So if my string is: "gads" I want to know the distance between g -> a, a -> d and d -> s

Comment: That makes more sense- `ord(let2) - ord(let1)` will get you the "alphabetical" distance, assuming you have an all lowercase string. But why do you want it just between indices 2 and 7?

Comment: I was only for testing.But I am fine now, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the documentation: `index` returns the position of the *first* occurrence of the given element.

Second, as soon as you find *any* qualifying index, you return from the function.  You never stay long enough to find any more indices.

Why do you "explode" the string into a list of individual characters?  You can iterate a string just as easily.

---

For your updated problem of getting the alphabetic difference, the solution is trivial: use the `ord` function, which returns the ordinal (ASCII code) of the character.

```
dist = []
prev = str[0]
for next in str[1:]:
    dist.append(abs(ord(prev) - ord(next)))
    prev = next
return dist
```

This returns the absolute distance between pairs of adjacent letters.

Given `str = "simpletext"`, we get the output

```
[10, 4, 3, 4, 7, 15, 15, 19, 4]
```

Comment: and use `index` on it (a string)

Answer (score -1):

Your error is the placement of your return statement. All you need to do is take it outside the for loop and return once the for loop is over.

```
def cos():
    x = "simpletext"
    testing = []
    for let in range(len(x)):
        if let > 2 and let < 7:
            testing.append(let)
    return testing

print(cos())
```

Comment: This will return: `[3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 6]` as the second `e` and `t` are also appended